# While installing Android Studio SDK component is not proposed to install?

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio-3.0

I don't have any previous versions of Android Studio and SDK's. But When i tried to install new one from official website unable to download SDK.

https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Can anyone please solve my issue.

[image]

Thanks in advance for reply... :)

Answer (score 0):

At first you install Android Studios. Then you can download and add SDK's you needed. But at first you have to install Android-Studios.